# src attribute with HTTP Range header for <audio> element in HTML5

Tags: html, html5-audio

How can I provide HTTP range header in src element of HTML5  element? I need to point audio element to source audio from byte offset X.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than specifying byte offset, you can change `currentTime` value of your `audio` element.

The value should be a real number in unit of seconds;

```
var url = "your/audio/path.mp3";
var audio = new Audio(url);
audio.addEventListener("play", function() {
    audio.currentTime = 10;  // jump to 00:10
});
audio.play();
```

It will make browser to jump to certain position of audio, requesting with HTTP range header as necessary.